# Set ACF user field and update post after gravity forms submission

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, gravity-forms-plugin

I am using Gravity Forms advanced post submission extension which is creating a CPT called invoices. Everything seems to work except that I'm not seeing the ACF values on the front end until I click to edit the post, and then click update.

I reached out to Gravity Forms and they said I should be using the code below, but it's not working.

Any ideas would be appreciated. I'm at my wits end.

```
function set_post_content( $entry, $form ) {
 
    //getting post
    $post = get_post( $entry['post_id'] );
 
    //changing post content
    $post->post_content = 'Blender Version:' . rgar( $entry, '7' ) . "<br/> <img src='" . rgar( $entry, '8' ) . "'> <br/> <br/> " . rgar( $entry, '13' ) . " <br/> <img src='" . rgar( $entry, '5' ) . "'>";
 
    //updating post
    wp_update_post( $post );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to output if there is an error in wp_update_post()? Furthermore, this function can cause infinite loop for save_post action.

Try to change the code to this:

```
function set_post_content( $entry, $form ) {

//getting post
$post = get_post( $entry['post_id'] );

//changing post content
$post->post_content = 'Blender Version:' . rgar( $entry, '7' ) . "<br/> <img src='" . rgar( $entry, '8' ) . "'> <br/> <br/> " . rgar( $entry, '13' ) . " <br/> <img src='" . rgar( $entry, '5' ) . "'>";

//updating post
$updated_post = wp_update_post( $post, true );

if (is_wp_error($updated_post )) {
    $errors = $updated_post->get_error_messages();
    foreach ($errors as $error) {
        echo $error;
    }
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can check if post revisions are enabled for invoices CPT.